# Finding a Javascript structure in an array based on one field

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am pushing a structure to an array which looks like the following

```
arr.push( {age: 32, name: "Joe"} );
arr.push( {age: 93, name: "Mike"} );
arr.push( {age: 19, name: "Billy"} );
```

What I would like to do is just find out if "Mike" is in the array.  Something like:

```
arr.includes({name: "Mike"})
```

I know this doesn't work but it shows what I'm looking for.

Comment: You're looking for `.find()` or `.findIndex()`

Comment: `arr.some(el => el.name === 'Mike')`

Answer (score 2):

you can use find in following way to get the targeted node from array of objects

`let result = array.find(t=>t.name=='Mike')`

Comment: Since the question was just whether it exists and not to get a reference to it, `some` will suffice though.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks.  Can't you tell I'm a C programmer :)